# Increase default Ubuntu sound volume?

Tags: sound, volume-control

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and the volume is too low for me. Even when I adjust to 100% volume, I can only hear a little from music.

I know that I can open the sound control and adjust to 150% volume, but If I want to use the mouse to adjust the sound icon on the status bar, I cannot adjust to 150%.

So, is there any way to increase the default volume?

Comment: What is the sound coming out of? Built-in speakers(if on a laptop), powered, or unpowered speakers connected to you PC?

Comment: yeah, build-in speakers, I'm using my laptop samsung series5.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which settings you see in the sound controls, but to be sure:

Take a look at the tabs "Playback" and "Output Devices" of `pavucontrol`.
It could be that "Playback" shows something like you had before, but 
"Output Devices" was not changeable from there, and maybe set to a low value.